# mysql select with time range and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
error_tbl                   success_tbl
id | creationTime           id|creationTime
1    2014-09-23 10:03:40    1212 2014-09-23 10:02:40
                            1213 2014-09-23 10:03:40
                            1214 2014-09-23 10:10:40
```

After run of query I want to have this:

```
result table
creationTime        | fail_ids | succ_ids
2014-09-23 10:03:40, 1,          NULL
2014-09-23 10:02:40, NULL,       1212 
2014-09-23 10:03:40, NULL,       1213
```

I want to select all data (success and fail) within time range of EACH AND EVERY 5 minutes only if any record exists in error_tbl within that period.

```
(SELECT
    creationTime, 
    id as  fail_ids,null as succ_ids
FROM error_tbl a

 UNION
SELECT
    creationTime,  
    null as fail_ids ,id as succ_ids
FROM success_tbl b
 ) s
```

Comment: "only if any record exists in error_tbl" => `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT something FROM error_tbl WHERE...)`

Answer (score 0):

Given the simplified schema with minor changes to make it look clean.

```
CREATE TABLE error(
  `error_id` INT, 
  `creation_time` DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO error(`error_id`, `creation_time`) VALUES   
  (1, '2014-09-23 10:03:40'),
  (2, '2014-09-23 10:04:05'),
  (3, '2014-09-24 10:08:04');

CREATE TABLE success(
  `success_id` INT, 
  `creation_time` DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO success(`success_id`, `creation_time`) VALUES
  (1212, '2014-09-23 10:02:40'),
  (1213, '2014-09-23 10:03:40'),
  (1214, '2014-09-23 10:10:40');
```

This should work, though I don't expect it to perform well on big datasets.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    DATE_FORMAT(creation_time, '%Y-%m-%d %k:'), 
    LPAD(FLOOR(MINUTE(creation_time) / 5) * 5, 2, 0), 
    ':00'
  ) `creation_time`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(error_id) `error_ids`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(success_id) `success_ids`
FROM (
  (
    SELECT NULL success_id, error_id, creation_time 
    FROM error
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT success_id, NULL error_id, creation_time
    FROM success
  )
) un
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) / (5 * 60))
HAVING error_ids IS NOT NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle snippet](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcb40/3).

Comment: what I want to have result table

Comment: @tugce Oh, it is a different question then. I've adjusted the answer, take a look.

Comment: well thanks for the help but, I need result table as I specify(creationTime is important). Performance not a problem, but need to see the all record set of that 5 min if any error happened.

Comment: @tugce You're free to rename or alias the columns in my answer as you like. I've demonstrated the idea.